# defining a function to pass it as props, but I get a compiling error

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-props, react-component

I have a react component that is trying to pass a function to another component, the problem is that
I'm not being able to define the function, it throws a compiling error

```
export default function App() {

createActivity() {      // here I get an error: missing semicolon
    console.log("creating activity");
}

return ( 
    <div className = "App" >
       <Route path="/" component={ Header } />  
       <Route exact path="/" component={ShowSplashWindow} />  
       <Route path="/createactivitiy" render = {() =>
              <CreateActivity createActivity={this.createActivity} />} />
    </div>
    );
}
```

What am I missing?

Rafael

Comment: `function createActivity() {}`

Comment: ...or `createActivity() {` -> `const createActivity = () => {`. Had you been writing a function inside a class, you could do it the way you did it.

Comment: but when I declare it as so, I get other error saying "'createActivity' is declared but its value is never read", but I'm using it in <Route path="/createactivitiy" render = {() =>
<CreateActivity createActivity={this.createActivity} />} />

Comment: That error will go away when you get rid of the `this.` part

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You declared component as functional, but trying to create a class method.

You should either use class component:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {...
```

with 2 methods: `createActivity` and `render`.

Or declare your function and assign to constant

```
    const createActivity = () => ...
```

but use it without `this`:

```
   <CreateActivity createActivity={createActivity} />
```

Answer (score 1):

The function has to be declared as

```
const createActivity = () => {
    console.log("creando la actividad");
}
```

And  when passed as props, it should not be called with "this"

```
<CreateActivity createActivity={createActivity} />}
```